# How to fix "In Qt two timer to one function, use qmutex will qeventloop for sleep"

Tags: qt, timer, deadlock, qeventloop, qmutex

I have some code use qtcpsocket to write and read, 
    write-->sleep-->read;
and ui had 2 and more timer to use this function; by i want i run synchronous;so i add mutex to lock it; by it deadlock;

qt4; qt5;

```
void MainWindow::Start()
{
    pTimer = new QTimer(this);
    pTimer->setInterval(100);
    connect(pTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(OnTimer()) );
    pTimer->start();
    pTimer2 = new QTimer(this);
    pTimer2->setInterval(100);
    connect(pTimer2,SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(OnTimer()) );
    pTimer2->start();
}

void MainWindow::OnTimer()
{
    FunCal();   // in my real code it will MyObj.DoSometing();
}
void MainWindow::FunCal()
{
    qDebug()<<"log in fun...";
    QMutexLocker loc(&this->_mtx);
    qDebug()<<"getted lock in fun...";
    QEventLoop loop;
    QTimer::singleShot(100, &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();
    qDebug()<<"log out fun...";
}
```

I Want i run and out put as:
    log in fun...
    getted lock in fun ...
    log out fun...
    log in fun...
    getted lock in fun...
log out fun...

but It Run like this:
    log in fun...
    getted lock in fun ...
    log in fun....
    ---------------------------------no more ---------------------

Comment: it run like "log in fun...";"getted lock in fun...";"log in fun...";

Comment: Your question is not really clear.
Do you want to synchronize the function `FunCal()` so that it is executed at most once at a time?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the issue of OP results from a basic misunderstanding:

**`QTimer` doesn't introduce multithreading.

It's just a facility to queue events which will sent after a certain time.**

That's why, the `QEventLoop` is necessary to make it running at all.

However, it's still a deterministic execution and this is what probably happens inside the code of OP:

- `pTimer->start();` → starts first timer
- `pTimer2->start();` → starts second timer
- control flow returns to event loop of `QApplication` (not exposed in code)
- first timer becomes due and calls `MainWindow::FunCal()`
- `qDebug()<<"log in fun...";` → output of `log in fun...`
- `QMutexLocker loc(&this->_mtx);` → `this->_mtx` becomes locked
- `qDebug()<<"getted lock in fun...";` → output of `getted lock in fun...`
- `loop.exec();` → enter a nested event loop (Nested event loops are allowed in Qt.)
- second timer becomes due and calls `MainWindow::FunCal()` (Please, remember that it was immediately started after first with same interval time.)
- `qDebug()<<"log in fun...";` → output of `log in fun...`
- `QMutexLocker loc(&this->_mtx);` → PROBLEM!

To illustrate it further, imagine the following call stack at this point (above called below):

```
QApplication::exec()
QEventLoop::exec()
QEventLoop::processEvents()
QTimer::timerEvent()
QTimer::timeOut()
MainWindow::onTimer()
MainWindow::FunCal()
QEventLoop::exec()
QTimer::timerEvent()
QTimer::timeOut()
MainWindow::onTimer()
MainWindow::FunCal()
QMutexLocker::QMutexLocker()
QMutex::lock()
```

(Note: In reality, you will see much more entries in the call-stack which I considered as irrelevant details in this case.)

The problem is: This second call of `MainWindow::FunCal()` cannot lock the mutex because it is already locked. Hence, the execution is suspended until the mutex is unlocked but this will never happen. The locking of mutex happened in the same thread (in the first/outer call of `MainWindow::FunCal()`). Unlocking would require to return from this point but it cannot because it's suspended due to the locked mutex.

If you think this sounds like a cat byting into its own tail – yes, this impression is right. However, the official term is [Deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

The usage of a `QMutex` doesn't make much sense as long as there are no competing threads. In a single thread, a simple `bool` variable would do as well because there are no concurrent accesses possible in a single thread.

Whatever OP tried to achieve in this code: Concerning the event-based programming forced/required by Qt, the problem is simply modeled wrong.

In single threading, a function cannot be entered twice accept by

1. a (direct or indirect) recursive call
2. a call out of a triggered interrupt handler.

Leaving the 2. aside (irrelevant for OPs Qt issue), the recursive call happens explicitly due to establishing a second (nested) event loop. Without this, the whole (mutex) locking is unnecessary and should be removed as well.

To understand event-based programming in general – it's described in the Qt doc. [**The Event System**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html).

Additionally, I found [**Another Look at Events**](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq11-events.html) by Jasmin Blanchette which IMHO gives a nice little introduction into how the Qt event-based execution works.

**Note:**

Event-based programming can become confusing as soon as the amount of involved objects and signals becomes large enough. While debugging my Qt applications, I noticed from time to time recursions which I didn't expect.

A simple example: A value is changed and emits a signal. One of the slots updates a Qt widget which emits a signal about modification. One of the slots updates the value. Hence, the value is changed and emits a signal...

To break such infinite recursions, a `std::lock_guard` might be used with a simple DIY `class Lock`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>

// a lock class
class Lock {
  private:
    bool _lock;

  public:
    Lock(): _lock(false) { }
    ~Lock() = default;
    Lock(const Lock&) = delete;
    Lock& operator=(const Lock&) = delete;

    operator bool() const { return _lock; }
    void lock() { assert(!_lock); _lock = true; }
    void unlock() { assert(_lock); _lock = false; }
};
```

A sample object with

- a property-like member: `bool _value`
- a simplified signal emitter: `std::function<void()> sigValueSet`
- and a lock used to prevent recursive calls to `setValue()`: `Lock _lockValue`

```
// a sample data class with a property
class Object {
  private:
    bool _value; // a value
    Lock _lockValue; // a lock to prevent recursion

  public:
    std::function<void()> sigValueSet;

  public:
    Object(): _value(false) { }
    bool value() const { return _value; }
    void setValue(bool value)
    {
      if (_lockValue) return;
      std::lock_guard<Lock> lock(_lockValue);
      // assign value
      _value = value;
      // emit signal
      if (sigValueSet) sigValueSet();
    }
};
```

Finally, some code to force the lock into action:

```
#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__

int main()
{
  DEBUG(Object obj);
  std::cout << "obj.value(): " << obj.value() << '\n';
  DEBUG(obj.sigValueSet = [&](){ obj.setValue(obj.value()); });
  DEBUG(obj.setValue(true));
  std::cout << "obj.value(): " << obj.value() << '\n';
}
```

To keep things short, I connected a slot to the signal which directly sets value again while the signal is emitted.

Output:

```
Object obj;
obj.value(): 0
obj.sigValueSet = [&](){ obj.setValue(obj.value()); };
obj.setValue(true);
obj.value(): 1
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb3e779eecf9e889)</kbd>

For a counter-example, I excluded the test `if (_lockValue) return;` and got the following output:

```
a.out: main.cpp:18: void Lock::lock(): Assertion `!_lock' failed.
Object obj;
obj.value(): 0
obj.sigValueSet = [&](){ obj.setValue(obj.value()); };
obj.setValue(true);
bash: line 7: 12214 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b98805f80db091f6)</kbd>

This is similar to what happened in OPs case with the only difference that in my case double-locking just violated the `assert()`.

To make this complete, I exluded the lock guard `std::lock_guard<Lock> lock(_lockValue);` as well and got the following output:

```
execution expired
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97bc1747c286634d)</kbd>

The execution was trapped into an infinite recursion, and the online compiler aborted this after a certain time. (Sorry, coliru. I won't do it again.)

Comment: @danny Actually, my answer describes what you've done wrong but lacks to explain how to do it right. That's because I couldn't recognize in your question your actual problem (what you actually tried to solve). I assume you want to achieve a series of actions based on some timing. I would do this using an integral variable for a state. On timeout: do actions according to state, set next state, restart timer (with, may be, different interval), and return from signal handler. It's essentially that a signal handler returns immediately after processing. Otherwise, the event loop becomes stalled.

Comment: I think it might could be done simply using the Qt signals and slots mechanism alone. The slots triggered by the timers would send signals, the functions would exit, and the event loop would process the slots invoked by the signals in its own good time; which, unless a lot of GUI is going on, is pretty fast. I just recently used it to avoid having a function that needed to call itself, needlessly (and potentially deeply) recurse.